# Node.js MongoDB bulkwrite not inserting all records

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bulkinsert

I have written a node.js script for mongoDB data migration (around 1 million records).
The collection I am inserting on already has 4 million records. My goal is to take data from collection A and collection B, process it and then dump it to collection C. Collection C already has few duplicate records (around 300k duplicates, unique indexed on a field).

I used insertMany with {ordered : false} with batch size 3000. 700k records should have been inserted but actually only 200k were inserted.
I reduced the batch size to 1000, and all the 700k records were inserted.
I increased the batch size to 3000 and migrated records to a new collection with 0 initial records. All 1 million records were migrated.

Also tried bulkWrite. But again the same outcome.

Mongo driver version: `"mongodb": "^3.1.12"`

Mongo server version: `v3.4.17`

The insertMany code snippet

```js
function insertMany(db, collection, documents) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.collection(collection).insertMany(documents, { ordered: false }, (err, result) => {
            if(err && err.result && err.result) {
                if(err.result.result.writeErrors) {
                    write_errors = write_errors + err.result.result.writeErrors.length;
                } else {
                    actual_inserts = actual_inserts + result.result.nInserted;
                }
            } else {
                actual_inserts = actual_inserts + result.result.n;
            }
            return resolve(true);
        });
    });
}
```

The total number of documents passed to this function is always the same irrespective of any change in batch size. But the total documents inserted (fetched from insertMany result) differs with change in batch size.

Why does the Node.js mongo driver behave strangely in circumstances where we have duplicates? Do we have a cap on batch inserts?

Comment: When you are performing the inserts, is each insert succeeding? Failing? With what errors?

Comment: Added the code snippet. I use the insertMany result to deduce write errors and total inserts. But the insert count changes when I change the batch size. Ideally it should be the same.

Comment: Your code does not mention batch size.

Answer (score 0):

you already reviewed how the schema is defined, it may find a restriction of unique

Comment: I have a unique index on of the fields which causes duplicate index errors, but that shouldn't affect the inserts as it's an unordered insert.